# Understanding Apache Traffic

Tags: apache, ubuntu, linode

I run a 2GB RAM Linode (Ubuntu) that hosts a few WordPress websites. Recently my server has been OOMing and crashing and I have been up all night trying to find out what's causing it. I have discovered there I get an enormous influx of traffic (a tiny DoS) that brings the whole thing down.

I have access logs setup across all of the virtual hosts and I am using tcptrack to monitor activity on the server.

The traffic appearing in my access logs does not account for the traffic I am seeing on tcptrack. i.e. there are a dozen i.p. addresses that are constantly opening and closing connections on the server, but are nowhere to be seen in the access logs for each virtual host.

Clearly it's because these i.ps are not hitting the virtual hosts, but I have tried to set up access logs to monitor server-wide traffic so that I can see what requests their making but I'm really struggling.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, perhaps tcptrack is just too simplified to provide any meaningful insight?

Answer (score 0):

Start using `mod_security`

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#Installation_for_Apache

Debian has it which means Ubuntu likely does as well. You should also make sure the kernel is setup properly, search google for SYN_COOKIES. Look into iptables/shorewall etc. Shorewall is a package that wraps iptables. Iptables can be configured for detect floods and start dropping packets.